# Do the 「 なんやら」and 「なにやら」have the same meaning?

Tags: words

I have encountered the following sentence.

はあ　なんすか？... **なんやら**手つづきがあるようだけど　さっさとかたづけちゃってくれませんか。

I have searched meaning of the word on several web sites but I only found the meaning of 「なにやら」. I'm not sure if they are interchangeable.

In addition, can I replace the word 「あるよう」with 「ありさま」without losing the original meaning?

Answer (score 2):

なんやら is just slurred なにやら.

あるよう means "it seems there are" and is never interchangeable to ありさま or ありよう.